# How do we prove that the left singular vectors form a basis for the column space of $A$?

Tags: linear-algebra

I need to prove that left singular vectors form a basis for the column space of $A$ and how do we find a basis for the null space of $A$ using singular vectors. Please help!

Comment: Do you know singular value decomposition?